# Mean block in SIMULINK not behaving as expected

Tags: matlab, mean, simulink, moving-average, simscape

In a SIMULINK file, I used the mean block. I do not know how to interpret the results. Before adding the block, the signal's value is zero. After adding the mean block, the signal's value changes after one cycle as shown below:

[image: top left is the signal when there is no mean block (~0). AT the bottom you see the signal and its average value. Frequency of the mean block is 60 Hz.]

I cannot understand the mean block's response after one cycle (T = 1/60 s).

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the time step. I assumed by choosing the default value (0), the model's time step will be inherited but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the fundamental frequency must be 0 Hz in dq reference frame.